# Profiling Javascript statement count

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging, execution

I recently ran into a long-running script error in IE but no other browsers. In investigatng further, I learned that IE defines a long-running script as one that executes more than 5,000,000 statements while all other browsers based in on execution time. In looking at all of the profilers I could find such as Firebug, they give a lot of information about memory usage, execution time, number of function calls but nothing about the number of statements executed.

Does anyone know of a profiler that can help me identify the number of statements executed (ideally grouped by function call)?

Answer (score 1):

[dynaTrace AJAX Edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/) is an *excellent* tool for this (profiling IE specifically), and it's free to boot.

You can debug/profile JavaScript, requests, CPU usage, see where you're spending all your processing time, which methods are called how many times, etc.  [Get started with the tutorials here](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/learn/Default.aspx).

Comment: Nick, Thanks for the hint about dynaTrace. It does look like a great tool. I've spent time reviewing the functionality but I couldn't find anywhere where it profiles the actual number of statements being executed. Reading through their documentation makes it appear all the profiling is time-based (similar to Firebug).
Have you used it to profile number of statements being executed?

Comment: @Steve - Yes I have, it gives you a full call tree, including CPU time as well as call count to each function...so you can see both how many calls and where the call's are coming from, easy to find what's looping that shouldn't be, etc.